# how programming a business rule on a trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to programm a business rule in a trigger using MySQL, but it doesn't work.

What I want to do is that if the condition is false then the insert must fail and rollback it. The problem is that MySQL doesn't permit using rollback inside a trigger.

I've also tried to use SIGNAL and text message but it fails.

The code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_NewTeacher
AFTER INSERT ON teachers FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (salary > 1300 AND budget < 15000)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END             
END
```

Comment: why after insert, why not before? No need to rollback then

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL trigger will rollback transaction if it fails.

So, you must raise exception within trigger body:

```
...
if [Test]
    then

      SIGNAL sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "No way ! You cannot do this !";

    end if ;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `before insert` and for getting the column values you need to use `new`

So the trigger would be as

```
delimiter //
create trigger tr_NewTeacher before insert on teacher
for each row 
begin
  if new.salaRY>1300 AND new.budget<15000  then
  signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Your error message';
 end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Here is a test case in mysql

```
mysql> create table teacher (id int auto_increment primary key,salaRY int , budget int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger tr_NewTeacher before insert on teacher
    -> for each row 
    -> begin
    ->   if new.salaRY>1300 AND new.budget<15000  then
    ->   signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Your error message';
    ->  end if;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)


mysql> insert into teacher (salaRY,budget) values (1200,16000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into teacher (salaRY,budget) values (1400,13000);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Your error message
mysql> select * from teacher ;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | salaRY | budget |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |   1200 |  16000 |
+----+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was sure that it could be an after insert.

Comment: No its better to do with before insert instead of doing rollback.